# How to get rid of this error coming in google play console? libflutter.so no found?

Tags: android, flutter

Summary of error message is;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bundle_id/com.example.vinscan.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[... couldn't find "libflutter.so"
```

I am trying to upload my app to play store ad getting the error. my application is using google ml kit for barcode scanning and text scanning. HTTP for API calls.
And there is google ads integrations as well.

Comment: Verify that your Gradle configuration is correct. Ensure that the Flutter dependencies are properly configured in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Relinker](https://github.com/KeepSafe/ReLinker) to resolve this issue. I have implemented this and the crash was gone.